# How can I combine application launchers into one launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop, quicklists

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My launcher is full of icons and I want to categorize it by creating separate folders for each category. Is it possible? If yes then please explain me how to do it.

Comment: I can't write an answer currently (on mobile), but see http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/qle-unity-quicklist-editor-20-released.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you, I installed it and now struggling to work with it... :(

Comment: @JacobVlijm please provide this as an answer.  see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15678/is-it-ok-to-comment-and-see-if-it-works-before-answer :-P

Comment: @LittleByBlue you're totally right, even posted an answer there :), but I am handicapped on mobile atm. Will post later for sure.

Comment: Unity Dash allows filtering by application type. See http://imgur.com/a/CVXFO

Comment: @Serg Thank you. But I want to do it on the launcher

Comment: Hi Nuwan, added my answer. Did you manage?

Comment: Just saw the answer.. busy a bit.. will tell you the result soon.. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### GUI quicklist editor

Combining (commands to start-) applications is one of the options of [QLE Unity Quicklist Editor](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/qle-unity-quicklist-editor-20-released.html?m=1). Although you *can* create a new icon and add your applications, I'd suggest adding your application shortcuts to an existing launcher icon, like below:

[image]

#### Adding applications to an existing icon

1. In the QLE main window, In the left column, you'll find the current Launcher items, click on the launcher you'd like to edit (`Gimp` in our example):

   [image]

   In the right column, you'll see possible quicklist (right-click) items of the launcher (currently none).
2. Click on the [image] icon, a drop-down list will appear, choose, "Add an application shortcut":

   [image]
3. In the (alphabetical) list that appears, pick your application and click "Add". Repeat untill all the applications you want to add to the iconb are added.

   [image]

*That's it.* This way you can save a lot of space in your Unity Launcher.

#### Note

The quicklist editor is currently being rewritten in `Gtk`, mainly for "cosmetical" (appearance) reasons. The current version still works fine in 16.04 though.

#### To install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/qle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qle
```

Comment: Where can one get the Gtk version? I do not like Tk.

Comment: @LittleByBlue ^ could be several months at least.

Comment: It only adds items to the right click menu of the icon? isn't it? No app icons?

Comment: @Nuwan Sure, wasn't that what you asked for? You mentioned wanting to save space in the launcher.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, thank you very much for that answer... it does what I wanted... what I am trying to mention here is, it is not eye-catching... isn't it? anyway.. thank you for the answer..