# how to make android like app folders on ubuntu desktop

Tags: launcher, .desktop

If you work with a smartphone, you can combine some app icons in one folder. those app icons only pop up when you click on the folder.

Is it possible to make something like that on your Ubuntu 16.04 desktop? so that you can hide some shortcuts in one small container. id like to put my libreoffice shortcuts on my desktop, but not on large view.

Comment: Why not use the LO quicklist? (or create one?) http://askubuntu.com/questions/798971/how-can-i-combine-application-launchers-into-one-launcher-icon/800422#800422

Comment: there are some other cases i would use it for